# Site home page not redirecting to prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, prerender

Have a site built with Angular 1.5 that is using prerender.io to server pages to bots.  For the most part it is working well, however, The home page of the site does not appear to be redirecting to prerender which is causing me some issues.  The path to my index file for angular is /templates/index.html.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg|\.eot|\.woff2))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/$2 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml$ http://content.example.com/$1.xml [P]
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^(.*) templates/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$     /$1$2/ [L,R=301]



Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

Not great with htaccess or httpd.conf.  Took over this from another developer.  Any insite would be a great help.

Comment: Make sure to change `http://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/$2` to include your domain instead of example.com. Also you might want to move the prerender config just below `RewriteEngine on`. Feel free to email us at support@prerender.io if you need help!

Comment: yes my proper domain is in place. Thank you.  I did move it up to just below RewriteEngine on

Comment: have you tried downloading their test server which allows you to test your configuration on localhost using `localhost?_escaped_fragment_` Do you get any errors or does the site load fine?